# Magento Error On Search

Tags: php, magento

I am modifying a magento template, and when ever a search is done for a product, I receive this error message.

Filter:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getParentId() on a non-object in /home1/ladykis9/public_html/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml on line 119

[image]
That template file is used throughout the store, to show a filter and the error only comes up on this page.  The url for the site is www.ladykismet.com and you will see that filter does not through any errors on the other pages it is used.  Thanks.

```
<?php 
   $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
    echo '<ul class="links"><li>Filter:</li>';

//echo $currentCat->getId();

if ( $currentCat->getParentId() == Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId())
{
    // current category is a toplevel category
    $loadCategory = $currentCat;

    $subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren());

    foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
        {
            $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

            if($cat->getIsActive())
                {
                    echo '<li><a href="'.$cat->getURL().'"><p>'.$cat->getName().'</p></a></li>';
            }
        }
    }
else
{
```

Comment: What's the stuff around line 119 of that file look like?

Comment: This error normally shows up when you don't have parent categories

Comment: @Mike I added the code to the post.  I am thinking a couple ways around it would be to remove the toolbar from the search page, cause it really is not needed.  What I think is happening, since a category is not being selected, it is unable to call on the currentCat object.

Comment: That or maybe just check that `$currentCat` is non-null before calling methods on it.